# password protect access 2010 options

Tags: security, ms-access, password-protection

I understood that it is possible to set a password to an access database to prevent users from opening it.

But is it also possible to set a password to prevent people from changing the "current database" options in the "Options" section?

I'm looking for a feature similar to Excels "Protect Workbook" method.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after ?

1.Open Microsoft Access 2010 and open the database that you wish to password protect in exclusive mode. You may do this by selecting Open from the file menu and navigating to the database you'd like to encrypt and then click it once. Then, instead of just clicking the Open button, click the downward arrow icon to the right of the button. Choose "Open Exclusive" to open the database in exclusive mode.

2.When the database opens, go to the File tab and click the Info button.

3.Click the Encrypt with Password button.

4.Choose a strong password for your database and enter it in both the Password and Verify boxes in the Set Database Password dialog box, as shown in the image above. Once you've done this, click OK.

Comment: Tanks for your answer. But no, this approach, as far as I understand it, does only set a password to prevent not allowed users to open the database.