# Access 2010: user login or restrict records to users

Tags: ms-access

is it possible in MS Access 2010 to restrict the records a user can see in a dataview form? For example User A should only see records from department A, whereas User B should only see records from department B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a query which uses your business rule as a constraint to return only the subset of rows the user should be allowed to access.  Then build your form with that query as its record source.

That approach depends on 2 conditions:

1. You have a method to identify the current user.
2. You can implement your business rule as a query `WHERE` clause.

You can use an API method to get the Windows account name of the current user.  See an example at [Get Login name](http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0008.htm).  If your db file is MDB format, you could set up ULS (user level security), and get the Access user name with the `CurrentUser()` function.  ULS is not supported in the newer ACCDB format, but Access 2010 can still use MDB format db files.

Either of those approaches could satisfy the first condition.  You could also develop code to manage custom user accounts, but that seems like too much extra work to me.

Something like this could implement your business rule as a query `WHERE` clause.  It uses the `fOSUserName()` function from the link above.

```
WHERE
    department = Switch(
        fOSUserName() = 'User A', 'department A',
        fOSUserName() = 'User B', 'department B')
```

However, a less brittle approach would be to inner join a table which contains the user names matched with the department(s) they should be allowed to view.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply. Will try out your approach tomorrow. One question that I have: are you sure that it is possible to call a vba function in an access query as you did in your example? Or will this only be possible in a vba macro.

Comment: As long as you're running the query from within an Access application session, yes, your query can use a user-defined function.  We do it routinely.  If you will be running a query from outside Access (like from classic ASP, VBScript, Dot.Net, etc.), the query will not be able to use a UDF ... the same as it cannot use certain VBA functions such as `Nz()`.

Comment: Perfect. It works as you described. Thanks for your help. I found also another/shorter way to get the windows login user name 'user_name = Environ("USERNAME")'.

Comment: Beware that `Environ("USERNAME")` can be easily defeated.  A user can open a command window, change `USERNAME` to a fake value, and start Access from that environment.  Use the Windows API to determine user name if you care about security.

Comment: As you seem to have a lot of experience working with Access, I wanted to ask you whether you have an idea to protect / hide the database structure from the user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687481/password-protect-access-2010-options

Comment: Make a copy of your db file, open it, then select Make ACCDE (or MDE) from the Database Tools section of the ribbon.  If that doesn't offer enough protection for the database structure I would next consider migrating the data to a client server db; SQL Server is a popular choice with Access.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the message "Microsoft Access was unable to create  the .accde, .mde, or .ade file. Without more details / or a proper error message. It just shows me in the help associated with the error that this most likely happens with databases having a lot of tables, forms etc. However I have 10 tables, 15 queries, 7 forms. This cannot be the issue. But thanks for your help! Unfortunately SQL Server is not an option.

Comment: ah now it works :) I had to compile the vba code first, and fix an issue and now the file was created successfully: http://tiny.cc/9l13ow

Comment: hmm.. I still can edit the tables in the compiled database. The only change I recognize is that I cannot enter anymore the VBA Code, which is good. However, for me it seems as there is also no way back when you compiled it once. Thus if I deploy the DB to the users in ACCDE and want to make a change in the vba after a few months, I will not be able to do it. I'm really wondering why MS did not included a simple password protection like in Excel.

Comment: Sorry, I now realize my suggestion was misguided.  Since you can't use a client-server db, I don't have anything more to offer.

Comment: ... unless you use MDB format for your db file.  Then apply Jet ULS (user level security) and deny the users design privileges on your tables.  But ULS can be challenging to set up properly, and you would need give the users access to the associated workgoup security file (MDW).  At least that's how I recall it.  I haven't used ULS recently, and hope I'm not steering you wrong again.  You should be able to find better info by seaching: Jet user level security.

Comment: thanks for your help. Not sure how to proceed, as it seems there is nothing appropriately build-in in access 2010.